# Cut unix variable

Tags: bash, unix, cut

I have the following at the moment:

```
for file in *
  do
  list="$list""$file "`cat $file | wc -l | sort -k1`$'\n'
  done

echo "$list"
```

This is printing:

```
fileA 10
fileB 20
fileC 30
```

I would then like to cycle through `$list` and `cut` column 2 and perform calculations.

When I do:

```
for line in "$list"
  do
     noOfLinesInFile=`echo "$line" | cut -d\  -f2`
     echo "$noOfLinesInFile"
  done
```

It prints:

```
10
20
30
```

BUT, the `for loop` is only being entered once. In this example, it should be entering the `loop` 3 times.

Can someone please tell me what I should do here to achieve this?

Comment: If 3 values are being printed that means loop is running 3 times.

Comment: @anubhava I printed out some random text after `echo "$noOfLinesInFile"` and this only printed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you quote the variable

```
for line in "$list"
```

there is only one word, so the loop is executed just once.

Without quotes, `$line` would be populated with any word found in the `$list`, which is not what you want, either, as it would process the values one by one, not lines.

You can set the `$IFS` variable to newline to split `$list` on newlines:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $list ; do
   ...
done
```

Don't forget to reset IFS to the original value - either put the whole part into a subshell (if no variables should survive the loop)

```
(
  IFS=$'\n'
  for ...
)
```

or backup the value:

```
IFS_=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for ...
    IFS=$IFS_
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because list in shell are just defined using space as a separator.

```
# list="a b c"
# for i in $list; do echo $i; done
a
b
c
# for i in "$list"; do echo $i; done
a b c
```

in your first loop, you actually are not building a list in shell sens.
You should setting other than default separators either for the loop, in the append, or in the cut...

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=()
linecounts=()

for file in *; do
    files+=("$file")
    linecounts+=("$(wc -l < "$file")")
done

for i in "${!files[@]}" ;do
    echo "${linecounts[i]}"
    printf '%s %s\n' "${files[i]}" "${linecounts[i]}"  ## Another form.
done
```

Although it can be done simpler as `printf '%s\n' "${linecounts[@]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

`wc -l` will only output one value, so you don't need to sort it:

```
for file in *; do
    list+="$file "$( wc -l < "$file" )$'\n'
done
echo "$list"
```

Then, you can use a while loop to read the list line-by-line:

```
while read file nlines; do
    echo $nlines
done <<< "$list"
```

That while loop is fragile if any filename has spaces. This is a bit more robust:

```
while read -a words; do
    echo ${words[-1]}
done <<< "$list"
```